# javascript: sorting an array of objects derives inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am working to sort an array of objects in descending order using pure javascript.  I initially thought that a JSON.stringify method was causing the issue, as described [here][1].  Apparently JSON.stringify does not preserve the order of objects by design. Give the below array of objects I seem to get a random sort order using the following code where I sort the array of objects and then derive the weight property of the first object in the array.

```
var byWeight = objArray.slice(0);
var sorted = byWeight.sort(function(a,b) { return b.weight - a.weight; } );
sorted[0].something.weight;
```

On distinct runs of this code, I seem to randomly derive .29 or .35 for the weight. Why is this occurring?

Here is the array:

```
[
  {
    "something": {
      "terms": [
        {
          "elements": {
            "number": {
              "span": [
                9,
                10
              ],
              "value": "1"
            }
          },
          "span": [
            9,
            12
          ],
          "value": "1g",
          "label": "grams"
        }
      ],
      "span": [
        9,
        12
      ],
      "weight": 0.29,
      "value": "1gm"
    }
  },
  {
    "something": {
      "terms": [
        {
          "elements": {
            "number": {
              "span": [
                16,
                18
              ],
              "value": "30"
            }
          },
          "span": [
            16,
            20
          ],
          "value": "30ml",
          "label": "liters"
        }
      ],
      "span": [
        16,
        20
      ],
      "weight": 0.35,
      "value": "30ml"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks to me as if it should be `b.something.weight - a.something.weight`

Comment: Separately: *"Apparently JSON.stringify does not preserve the order of objects"*. It can't. [Javascript object properties don't *have* an order to preserve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order),

Comment: Your objArray is poorly formatted, "terms" shouldn't be an array if it contains key-indexed elements like "span", "value", and "label' it should be an object. it works fine if you change that: http://jsfiddle.net/s4k3t1Lo/

Comment: @JKirchartz  Correct objArray.  error was introduced during simplification for presentation here. - OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong reference. Change this

```
var sorted = byWeight.sort(function(a,b) { return b.weight - a.weight; } );
```

to (watch `.something.`)

```
byWeight.sort(function (a, b) { return b.something.weight - a.something.weight; });
```

**Working model:**

```js
var data = [
  {
      "something": {
          "terms": {
              "span": [
              9,
              12
              ],
              "value": "1g",
              "label": "grams"
          }
      ,
          "span": [
          9,
          12
          ],
          "weight": 0.29,
          "value": "1gm"
      }
  },
  {
      "something": {
          "terms": {
              "span": [
              16,
              20
              ],
              "value": "30ml",
              "label": "liters"
          }
      ,
          "span": [
          16,
          20
          ],
          "weight": 0.35,
          "value": "30ml"
      }
  }
];

var sorted = data.slice(0);
sorted.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.something.weight - a.something.weight; // desc!
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Not quite.  I need it in descending order.  But you were half right in that I was omitting "something" from "return a.something.weight - b.something.weight"  So this works: "byWeight.sort(function (a, b) { return b.something.weight - a.something.weight; });"

Comment: I don't think you should have deleted the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your objArray is poorly formatted, "terms" shouldn't be an array if it contains key-indexed elements like "span", "value", and "label' it should be an object; then your sort is looking in the wrong place, it should be looking at `a.something.weight`/`b.something.weight` instead. [jsfiddle.net/3qgtn9r1](http://jsfiddle.net/3qgtn9r1/)

```
var objArray = [
  {
    "something": {
      "terms": {
          "span": [
            9,
            12
          ],
          "value": "1g",
          "label": "grams"
      },
      "span": [
        9,
        12
      ],
      "weight": 0.29,
      "value": "1gm"
    }
  },
  {
    "something": {
      "terms": {
          "span": [
            16,
            20
          ],
          "value": "30ml",
          "label": "liters"
      },
      "span": [
        16,
        20
      ],
      "weight": 0.35,
      "value": "30ml"
    }
  }
];
var byWeight = objArray.slice(0);
var sorted = byWeight.sort(function(a,b) { return a.something.weight - b.something.weight; } );
console.log(sorted[0].something.weight);
```

Comment: Halfway there, but how does that solve the sorting problem?

Comment: This does not solve the sorting problem; it still has the exact same bug.

Comment: I introduced an error in the array object while simplifying it for presentation here.  Corrected -- OP